# Shimano 9 Speed Cassette with Microshift Advent 9 Speed Road Shifter

Tags: derailleur, cassette, parts

I fancy setting up my old but amazing Cannondale F1000 with a dropbar and corresponding road shifters.The only affordable system I could find for that is the Microshift Advent 9 group. I'm happy with their SB-M090 shifters as well as the RD-M6195M rear derailleur, but do not looking forward using their massive and heavy 11-42T cassette. Now I wonder whether the Microshift 9-speed RD-M6195M derailleur would work with a less heavy Shimano 11-32T cassette like the XT CS-M770? Does anyone have experience or insights whether that combination would work?

Comment: Shimano Sora should be affordable as well. Do you really want to exchange everything? Some shifters could be compatible with your existing derailleurs.

Comment: Shimano 9-speed drop-bar shifters should be compatible with any existing Shimano 9-speed rear derailleur (road or MTB).

Comment: If you only want to run 11-32 cassette, Advent is the wrong group set.   Better to look at a road groupset - like Microshift R9 or (as suggested)  Sora.  What constraints do you have that steered you towards Advent.  (Advent is great but built specifically for a cheap 1x MTB setup with a wide range cassette)